# how to put bottom menu in android app

Tags: android, menu, styles, geometry

I want to create a bottom menu in android application like that : 
[image]

I wrote the code below but it return me something wrong

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/bar_bas"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_circle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                
            android:textColor="#bfd2b0"
            android:background="@drawable/right_left"
            android:text="test" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_circle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                
            android:textColor="#bfd2b0"
            android:background="@drawable/left_circle"
            android:text="test" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_circle"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-6dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                
            android:textColor="#bfd2b0"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:text="test" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_circle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                
            android:textColor="#bfd2b0"
            android:background="@drawable/right_circle"
            android:text="test" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_circle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                
            android:textColor="#bfd2b0"
            android:background="@drawable/right_left"
            android:text="test" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I divided this picture to five buttons one of them is circular and two square and two ..

here is how it is displayed :

[image]

how can I fix this issue

Comment: What does "but it return me something wrong" mean? What was wrong about it? Do you have a screenshot depicting the incorrect behavior?

Answer (score 0):

A `LinearLayout` will simply show each of its child Views sequentially. It does not support layering, overlapping, or stacking Views on top of each other.

I suggest switching to a `RelativeLayout`, which does support overlapping Views.

Another option would be to simply adjust where you are defining the bounds of each button's background, to something like this, which would work in a `LinearLayout`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use a relative layout and align it to bottom. inside this have seperate relative layouts for one button and a divider. and the next relative layout placed to the rightofthefirst with another button and divider. Do it like this.

```
  <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
                android:layout_width="85dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null" 
                android:clickable="true">


                    <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageview1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/some_drawable"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/divider1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/menu_divider" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
                android:layout_width="85dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/relativeLayout1"
                android:clickable="true" >


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageview2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/some_drawable"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/divider2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/menu_divider" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I used it, it works,  but I have to adjust this menu to all screens, size, because if I change emulator the menu is not adjusted